# Crear array segun la primera letra

Tags: php, array, symfony

Hola comunidad tengo un `array` ordenado ALFABETICAMENTE pero si en el nombre se repite dos veces **jose - jose** crear un `array` nuevo con la `key` de `J` es decir un `array` con las primeras letras de cada nombre si se repite se asigna ese nombre al mismo `array` ya que puede tener nombre repetido pero apellido distinto.

#### `array`

```
array(
  array(
    "id" => "30",
    "name" => "kiosera",
    "second_name" => "delim",
    "lastname"=> "kinsi"
  ), 
  array(
    "id" => "30",
    "name" => "king",
    "second_name" => "surrd",
    "lastname"=> "kinsi"
  ), array( 
    "id" => "30",
    "name" => "gustavo",
    "second_name" => "simplify",
    "lastname"=> "kinsi"
  ), array(
    "id" => "30",
    "name" => "grandi",
    "second_name" => "simplify",
    "lastname"=> "kinsi"
  )
)
```

Comment: Podrás editar la pregunta y agregar lo que has hecho hasta ahora? Así evítas puntos negativos o que te cierren la pregunta.

Comment: Si no pones lo que has hecho hasta ahora parecera que quieres que hagamos todo por ti y este sitio no tiene esa finalidad. Pon un poco de código de lo que has intentado hacer.

Comment: [
  array(

   "id" =>  "30",
      "name" => "kiosera",
      "second_name" => "delim",
      "lastname"=> "kinsi"

  ),

  array(

   "id" =>  "30",
      "name" => "king",
      "second_name" => "surrd",
      "lastname"=> "kinsi"

  ),

  array(

   "id" =>  "30",
      "name" => "gustavo",
      "second_name" => "simplify",
      "lastname"=> "kinsi"

  ),

  array(

   "id" =>  "30",
      "name" => "grandi",
      "second_name" => "simplify",
      "lastname"=> "kinsi"

  )
 ]

Comment: quiero que sea un array ordenado segun la letra A => [], B => []